# How to use loop indicator as a "name placeholder" for assignments?

Tags: r, loops, variable-assignment, assign

Let me jump right into an example:

```
 a <- list()
 b <- list()
 c <- list()
 i.list <- list(a,b,c)

 for(i in i.list){ i[[1]] <- "some entry" }
```

This won't work, and my question is twofold:

- How do I make it work?
- Why does it not work?

When I use

```
 for(i in i.list){ print(class(i)) }
```

I get that `i`, i.e. the loop indicator, is recognized as a list, which is exactly what I expect. It is my understanding that when I want to add something to a list, I can use assignments such as

```
 a[[1]] <- "some entry"
```

which indeed works when I do it manually. When used in the aforementioned list, it does not appear to work, though, which puzzles me a bit. It is my understanding that the following happens in the `for`-loop: In the first iteration, `i` assumes the first value of `i.list`, and the command should be evaluated as `a[[1]] <- "some entry"`. In the second iteration, this becomes `b[[1]] <- "some entry"`, etc. But apparently, this does not happen.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this work, and most importantly clear up why it won't work? What is wrong with my understanding of what happens in the loop?

Note: I know that many people here will advise against using a loop, and I completely agree with that. However, I only have a couple of elements to loop over, and the clarity of the `for`-loop outweighs any efficiency gains in my particular application. Moreover, at the very moment, it is more important for me to understand why this does not work, as I am genuinely curious to understand the R internals.

Comment: Why not just do  `for(i in length(i.list) ) i.list[[i]][[1]]<-something`  ?   Much quicker and easier

Comment: Well, I want to change the lists / dataframes etc in my workspace, not in that list (which I have created only for looping purposes, and which will be removed afterwards). I could of course put them into the list, change them, and "put them back" into my workspace afterwards, but that seems inelegant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem of scoping, e.g. this shows that your solutions "works":

```
for (i in i.list){ i[[1]] <- "some entry"; print(i) }
```

Because `i` is only defined in the local scope of the `for` loop the change does not affect your elements of `i.list` in the global environment.

This example should work like expected:

```
for (i in seq(along=i.list)) { i.list[[i]][[1]] <- "some entry" }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was easier than I thought. I wasn't aware that `for`-loops span local environments just as other functions (after all, `i` usually remains in the workspace after executing a loop, making me believe that it is not treated as a local variable). Do you by any chance have an idea how I could use `i` as a name holder to access the variable in .GlobalEnv instead of going over the list entries? I tried changing the list to character vectors and `get(i, envir=.GlobalEnv)[[1]] <- "some entry"` but this does not work... :(